# Iterate over properties in a static class

Tags: c#, properties, static

I have a static class which stores some parameters about my program, like the following,

```
public static class Parameters
{
    public static string Path = "C:\\path.txt";
    public static double Sigma = 0.001;
    public static int Inputs = 300;
}
```

I would like to have a function which gives all the `names` and `values` of this class as a string value, something like:

```
public static string LogParameters()
{
     return "Path = C:\\path.txt" + Envrironment.NewLine + 
            "Sigma = 0.001" + Environment.NewLine + 
            "Inputs = 300";
}
```

I tried this similar SO question, [How to loop through all the properties of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531384/how-to-loop-through-all-the-properties-of-a-class), however in this example they used a non-static class which they can refer as an object. So, I am unable to use their code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Those aren't properties - they are fields:

```
foreach(FieldInfo field in typeof(Parameters).GetFields()) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", field.Name, field.GetValue(null));
}
```

(obviously, adjust the above to write to a StringBuilder instead of to the Console)