# Loop through properties of one Object base type

Tags: c#, object, reflection

I have to iterate through property of one object base type that i get from database and i have to check if any property i snull. Here is some code:

```
 req = "select * from Ga_Periodes_Absence";
 var resultat = Session.CreateSQLQuery(req).List<object>();
 foreach (var elem in resultat)
 {
     int i = 0;

     i++;
 }
```

`resultat` contains list of objects that I want to check if property of any of them is null. Any help please.

Comment: There a number of answers in this site addressing this question, like [How to loop through all the properties of a class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531384/how-to-loop-through-all-the-properties-of-a-class). Please, do some research before posting.

Comment: you clearly do not need an index when you use a foreach, and if by any chance you really do, you do not create it inside the loop statement

Comment: Mr Andrei, iknow why i put  the index because i use it, the code is not complete.

Comment: Mr rae, i haven't time to search, and it not cause probleme to you

Answer (score 1):

```
bool result = true;    
foreach (var elem in resultat)
{
    foreach(var prop in elem.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if(prop.GetValue(elem) == null) result = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: the probleme with that is they retyrn properties of base class 'System.Object' rather than properties that i get from database