# How to loop through set values in Object property class in C#?

Tags: c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have this property class like:

```
public class ABC{

    public string a {get;set;}
    public int? b {get;set;}
    public string c {get;set;}
    public int? d {get;set;}
    public int? e {get;set;}
    public int? f {get;set;}  
}
    string lineabc = "8004CF::JAI2310:0:5:0";
    string[] splitrow = lineabc.Split(':');
```

I have to **loop through set all the values** in this object property class, the values which i want to set in the object class by **splitrow** array value.

***i don't want to set values one by one in class object property like*** :

```
ABC.a = splitrow[0];
```

Comment: You'll need to use reflection (specifically, the Type.GetProperties() method) to loop through the PropertyInfo array of the class, although reflection is not very performant.  You may want to take a step back and reevaluate what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to loop through all the properties of a class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531384/how-to-loop-through-all-the-properties-of-a-class)