# how to check if a string value exists in ReportParameter list c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a ReportParameter list called `lstParam` with few values.

```
List<ReportParameter> lstParam = new List<ReportParameter>();
ReportParameter rpm = new ReportParameter();    
rpm.Name = "Department";
rpm.Name = "Location";
lstParam.Add(rpm);
```

**Note:** `ReportParameter is used from reporting services rdlobject model`

Now I need to check if the list has a specific string value and the below code doesn't work for 'ReportParameter' list.

```
var matchingvalues = !lstParam.Where(stringToCheck => stringToCheck.Contains(stringValue));

if (!lstParam.Any(str => str.Contains(stringValue)))
  { 

  }
```

Both the above statement didn't help and I get the below error.

```
'ReportParameter' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension 
method overload 'Queryable.Contains<string>(IQueryable<string>,string)' 
requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable<string>'
```

**ReportParameter class:**

```
public class ReportParameter : ReportObject, INamedObject
{
    public ReportParameter();

    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool AllowBlank { get; set; }
    public DataTypes DataType { get; set; }
    public DefaultValue DefaultValue { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool Hidden { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool MultiValue { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(typeof(string))]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool Nullable { get; set; }
    [ReportExpressionDefaultValueAttribute]
    public ReportExpression Prompt { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue("")]
    [XmlChildAttributeAttribute("Prompt", "LocID", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner")]
    public string PromptLocID { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue(UsedInQueryTypes.Auto)]
    public UsedInQueryTypes UsedInQuery { get; set; }
    public ValidValues ValidValues { get; set; }

    protected override bool RdlSemanticEqualsCore(ReportObject rdlObj, ICollection<ReportObject> visitedList);
}
```

Really appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: ReportParameter is obviously not a string. Do you actually want to check against a particular string property of this object?

Comment: Can you show the ReportParameter class what it contains? Based on that we have to decide the implementation.

Comment: @Andrei - Yes, I want to check string value with lstParam list.

Comment: @SouvikGhosh - Updated my post.

Comment: I think you wish to check either the property Name or PromptLocID of any of the items in the list contains the stringvalue. Am I right? Please Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: It might be something like this- var matchingvalues = !lstDSParameter.Where(stringToCheck => stringToCheck.Name.Contains(stringValue));

Comment: Ya it could be either the way Souvik Ghosh has said above or it could be     
'var matchingvalues = !lstDSParameter.Where(stringToCheck => stringToCheck.Name.Contains(stringValue) || stringToCheck.PromptLocID.Contains(stringValue))'     if you wish to check for both

Comment: @SouvikGhosh - I am getting this error. `bool string.Contains(string value) (+ 2 overloads).Returns a value indicating whether the specified string object occurs within this string,
Operator '!' cannot be applied to operand of type 'IEnumerable<ReportParameter>'`

Comment: @SethuBala - I am getting the same error mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: `ReportParameter` only contains the definition of the report parameter not its runtime value.

Comment: How do you populate the `ReportParameter` list?  Please post the respective code.

Comment: It seems you are using the `ReportParameter` from the wrong namespace. Try using the one in the [Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportRendering Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reportingservices.reportrendering.aspx). This one contains a `Value` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check only if there ia any item that satisifes your condition, can you please try this code

```
bool matchingvalues = lstDSParameter.SelectMany(stringToCheck => stringToCheck.Name.Contains(stringValue) || stringToCheck.PromptLocID.Contains(stringValue)).ToList().Count > 0
```

Comment: Error message is thrown at SelectMany. `Try specifying the type arguments explicitly`

Comment: bool matchingvalues = lstDSParameter.Any(stringToCheck => stringToCheck.Name.Contains(stringValue) || stringToCheck.PromptLocID.Contains(stringValue));    
Can you please try this. This will return true if any item in the list satisfies either of the 2 conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You describe two lists: `lstParam` and `lstDSParameter`. I assume that is a typo and they are the same list.

Each element in `lstParam` is of type `ReportParameter`. If you use `Enumerable.Where`, every item in the were clause represents a `ReportParameter`. A ReportParameter is not a string, and thus you get the compiler error you described.

You say that you need to check *if the list has a specific string value*.

Well obviously, because the list does not contain strings, there isn't any. Therefore I assume that you need to check if a certain property of the elements in the sequence contains a specific string value. Let's assume you want to check if any of the Names of the ReportParameters in the sequence contains the specific string value.

To do this, you have to transform every element in the sequence to a string that contains the Name value of each element. In Linq, whenever you need to transform elements from a sequence into something else you use Enumerable.Select:

```
List<ReportParameter> lstParam = ...;
var reportParameterNames = lstParam.Select(reportParameter => reportParameter.Name);
```

"From every reportParameter in lstParam, take reportParameter.Name, and put these names in a new sequence called reportParameterNames"

Now to check if any of the reportParameterNames equals the `SpecificStringValue` you can use Enumerable.Any:

```
bool lstParamContainSpecificStringValue = reportParameterNames
    .Any(name => name == SpecificStringValue);
```

"Check if any element in the reportParameterNames sequence equals SpecificStringValue"

[This article](http://odetocode.com/articles/739.aspx) helped me to understand LINQ, and learned me how to use it

Comment: There is only one list and to be clear this is what I want actually `bool lstParamContainSpecificStringValue = lstDSParameter.Any(name => name == rpmObj.Name);` rpmObj is one of the reportparamter value from another list.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using the `ReportParameter` from the wrong namespace. Try using the one in the [Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportRendering Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reportingservices.reportrendering.aspx). This one contains a `Value` property.

MSDN [ReportParameter Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reportingservices.reportrendering.reportparameter.aspx)

So you can use it like this:

```
if (!lstParam.Any(p => p.Value?.ToString().Contains(stringValue)))
{ 

}
```

Comment: how about using `Name` property from the existing class?

Comment: @vicky `Name` is the report parameter's name not its value.  The question talks about checking for a specific **string value**, does that mean the parameter name or its value?  You already know the names, right? Department and Location.

Answer (score 0):

have look at the question [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531384/how-to-loop-through-all-the-properties-of-a-class).

may be reflection can help you here. 
I suggest you to 1st loop through the

```
    List<ReportParameter> lstParam = new List<ReportParameter>();
foreach(var item in lstParam )
{
//and then loop through class properties 
Type type = item.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();

foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties )
{
    //now here you can play with class properties 
//like property.Name or property.Value
//place your check here
}
}
```

I haven't tested this code, just suggesting you the path to go. I hope this will help, trying to find some other efficiente way to get rid of loops.