# How do I loop through all fields in an object in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have an object like this:

```
public class Filters {
    public int var1 = 1, 
          var2 = 2, 
          var3 = 3;
}
```

I declare this object here:

```
Filters filter1 = new Filters();
```

And I want to access `var1`, `var2`, and `var3` in a loop and do something with it. i.e.:

```
foreach (var prop in filter1.props) {
    Console.WriteLine(filter1[prop] + 3);
}
```

and the output would be:

```
4
5
6
```

I imagine I need to do a foreach loop for each property using 
`foreach(PropertyInfo p in filter1.GetType().GetProperties())`, but I don't know how to 1) loop through props var1, var2, var3, and 2) how to subset the prop from `filter1` using the name stored in the variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to loop through all the properties of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531384/how-to-loop-through-all-the-properties-of-a-class)

Comment: First of all, if you want to _" loop for each property"_, you need [Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties). Currently, you have no properties inside your `Filters` class.

Comment: But do you really want to use reflection? Why not simply have an `IDictionary<string,object>` called properties that you could iterate?

Comment: Note that they are [fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields) and not [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties).

Comment: Alternatively, use an array. You can have as many values as you like in those.

Comment: Have a public Property (not a Field) that exposes a Dictionary, or another specialized sub-class Properties.

Answer (score 5):

If you describe your variable as properties like bellow,

```
public class Filters
{
    public int var1 { get; set; } = 1;
    public int var2 { get; set; } = 2;
    public int var3 { get; set; } = 3;
}
```

You can access these properties with

> GetType().GetProperties()

then the main method will give you what you ask for

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Filters filter1 = new Filters();

    foreach (var prop in filter1.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", prop.Name, (int)prop.GetValue(filter1, null) + filter1.GetType().GetProperties().Length);
    }
        
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Result will be

```
var1=4
var2=5
var3=6
```

Comment: Only a minor addtition, but would the result (console output) not be `"var1=4"`, `"var2=5"` and `"var3=6"`?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone who answered-- a couple hints helped me get there. I just started in C# so I didn't know what fields/props were, so thanks @SeM @John. But with that, and with answers by @Icepickle & @arslanaybars with `GetProperties()` but for fields instead:

```
        FieldInfo[] fields = typeof(GeneralFilters).GetFields();
        for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
        {
            //MANIPULATE HERE
            BlankTemplate tempFilter = (BlankTemplate)fields[i].GetValue(filters);
            // Ignore this for now.       tempFilter.selectedItems;
        }
```

where BlankTemplate is defined here:

```
public class BlankTemplate
{
    public string[] selectedItems;
    public bool selectAll = false;
}
```

And now in `tempFilter` I have the object that I need to use at every iteration

Thanks!!!

Edit: I realize that this doesn't answer the question of how to subset using the stringified name of the object fields. What I envisioned before is generating array of field names, then looping through and subsetting the data in the fields using the field names, like in javascript:

```
var fieldNames = Object.keys(filterObject);
for (var i = 0; i < fieldNames.length; i++) {
    doSomething( filterObject[fieldNames[i]] );
}
```

But it seems to be a bit different in C#

Comment: if you really want it based on names, then an indexer can do wonders as well, you would get then the things from `blankTemplate["property"]` and get a string (or any kind of other properties) back.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative answer to your question could be the following, say you have a class of filters like the following

```
public class Filter 
{
    public IDictionary<string, object> Properties { get; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();
}
```

This would allow you to have a dynamic set of filters, you can assign new properties as a consumer and iterate the existing ones. That seems to fit your current requirements.

As for a real answer, as many in the comments have pointed out, if you want to iterate [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties), then you should actually use them. In your sample code, you have provided [fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields) instead.

So your class `Filter` would probably end up looking like this (note that I think var1...var3 are the most horrible names you can use as I cannot imagine what they might define in the end):

```
public class Filter 
{
    public int Var1 { get; set; } = 1;
    public int Var2 { get; set; } = 2;
    public int Var3 { get; set; } = 3;
}
```

and then you could have something similar like:

```
var filter = new Filter();
var filterType = filter.GetType();
var readableProperties = filterType.GetProperties().Where( p => p.GetGetMethod() != null );

foreach (var property in readableProperties) 
{
    var value = (int)property.GetValue( filter );
    Console.WriteLine( $"{property.Name} =  {value + 3}" );
}
```

To ensure that you only select those you actually want, you can ofcourse check the name if it equals to Var1, Var2, Var3 or matches a regex expression, or whatever you like to think of ;)

A sample of the code here, you can find in this [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kXJzmy) (though without autoproperties and $)