# Instead of using reflection to loop though a class properties, can i serialize it to json string and look through it? Are there any downsides to it?

Tags: c#, serialization, reflection, json.net

Assume i have a class like this below

```
class Student
{
public int ID { get; set; }

public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Just with 10 more properties. I want to loop through these properties. I can do it through reflection, which will have a performance cost. Is serializing it using Newtonsoft JSON and looping through it better?

---

Edit:
The reason i want to do this is there are many classes like this. Each of these classes also has a Ienumerable object as below

```
public bool Validation
{
public string PropName { get; set; }
public bool IsRequired { get; set; }
public int? MaxLength { get; set; }
public int? MinLength { get; set; }

public void Validate(object propValue)
{... }
}
```

I want to loop through each property in student class, take values and supply it to validate method. But i don't want to use reflection. I am not sure if it is even possible. Let me know if u have any thoughts.

Comment: Why not just try it out?

Comment: You would have to measure it. Considering that serializing it will use reflection, I seriously doubt the total cost will be lower.

Comment: What do you want to do in the loop?

Comment: Why do you want to loop the properties? Seems x-y to me.

Comment: Serializing comes with a cost too, likely using reflection as well, and then parsing the json  also has a cost. Is this really a hotspot in your program? Consider writing the code in a clear usable manner instead. If that becomes a hotspot on profiling then optimize as appropriate against the baseline you already have written.

Comment: I have edited this to add the 'Why'. Please note that existing code can't be changed too much. Any small tweaks to existing code is possible. There are too many reasons for this to give here.

Comment: Why don't you want to use reflection?

Comment: Yes it's possible to use Newtonsoft for this, but it might not be worth the trouble.  It is very easy to loop through the properties of a class and get their values after all, see [How to loop through all the properties of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/531384).  Are you going to be validating *many* `Student` objects?  Are you sure you have a performance problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are disturbed by performance hit of the reflection you can "cache" it using generic static classes and private static fields in them (which are not shared) and some compilation magic using [expression trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/). For example (modified your code to make it compile):

```
public static class Validator<T>
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, Func<T, object>> propGetters;
    static Validator()
    {
        propGetters = 
        typeof(T)
            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Where(p => p.GetGetMethod() != null)
            .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p =>
            {
                var par = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
                var access = Expression.Property(par, p);
                var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(Expression.Convert(access, typeof(object)), par);
                return lambda.Compile();
            });
    }   
    
    public static bool Validate(T c, IEnumerable<Validation> v)
    {
        return v.All(v => v.Validate(propGetters[v.PropName](c)));
    }
}

class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Validation
{
    public string PropName { get; set; }
    public bool IsRequired { get; set; }
    public int? MaxLength { get; set; }
    public int? MinLength { get; set; }

    public bool Validate(object propValue)
    { return false; }
}
```

Which can be used like this:

```
var x = new Student();
var validations = new[]
{
    new Validation
    {
        PropName = "Name",
        IsRequired = true,
        MinLength = 1,
        MaxLength = 10
    }
};
Validator<Student>.Validate(x, validations);
```

This code can be improved(for example if `IEnumerable<Validation>` is collection on the class itself you can move code getting it to another static property and remove corresponding parameter of `Validator.Validate`)

Comment: thanks @Guru. This is solves the performance problem of reflection to a large extent

Comment: @krishnaprasadparthasarathy was glad to help!

Comment: @guru-stronton - Just one question - There are around 200 student like classes and with each one having ~ 15 properties. So total of 3000 PropGetter Funcs. Will this have a big performance impact? I know there will have to be compromises some place. but i was just wanted to know the impact this would have.

Comment: @krishnaprasadparthasarathy you should benchmark your concrete case. Last time I checked compiled expression for getters were working with approximately the same speed as ordinary ones(though it can depend on framework/compiler version), also you will have some overhead on dictionary access, but in my experience both this factors never were  bottleneck in my app. Also you will have a little more memory needed to store 3000 PropGetter Funcs but it will constant(cause "caching", if you do not create classes dynamically) and less then dynamic string(json) manipulation/reflection.

Comment: @guru-stronton - Thanks. I will benchmark it n see.