# C# Template Function: Cannot do non-virutal member lookup in 'T' because it is a type parameter

Tags: c#, function, templates

I have a system where every interface/class has two codes (`InterfaceCode`, `SubtypeCode`) - this is for efficiently saving and re-generating objects from hex-strings.

I now have a specific usecase where I need a specific object of a class which inherites `Iitem`.
To check if the ItemCode matches the required interface/class I wanted to compare values with `T.InterfaceCode` and `T.SubtypeCode` (see below). Sadly this won't work because I cannot access members of a type parameter (`CS0704`).

```
public static T AsType<T>(string ItemCode) where T : Iitem
{
    if (ItemCode.Length < 5) return null;

    ItemCodeDes itemCode = new ItemCodeDes(ItemCode);

    if(itemCode.InterfaceCode != T.InterfaceCode) return null; //Error CS0704 Cannot do non-virtual member lookup in 'T' because it is a type parameter
    
    if(itemCode.SubtypeCode != T.SubtypeCode) return null; //same here...

    //...
}
```

with

```
public static ushort SubtypeCode { get; } = 0;
public static ushort InterfaceCode { get; } = 0;
```

I really don't wont to hardcode Lookup Tables for each class (there will be about 100-200).

Is there a good & clean solution to my problem (without using Reflection)?

Edit: I am still using C# .NET Core 3.1

For those who need more context:

```
public class Iitem
{
    public static ushort SubtypeCode { get; } = 0;
    public static ushort InterfaceCode { get; } = 0;
    public Iitem(string itemName, string description, ItemTier tier, ushort id)
    {
        Name = itemName;
        Tier = tier;
        Description = description;
        Id = id;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
    public string Description { get; }
    public ItemTier Tier { get; }
    public ushort Id { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gibt den itemspezifischen Code zurück.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Itemcode als Hex-String</returns>
    public virtual string GetItemCode()
    {
        return GenerateItemCode(0, 0);
    }
    internal string GenerateItemCode(ushort Interface, ushort Subtype, ulong Generationspecifics = 0)
    {
        return Interface.ToString("X1") + Subtype.ToString("X1") + Id.ToString("X3") + (Generationspecifics != 0 ? Generationspecifics.ToString("X") : "");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Generiert einen String mit den Stats und einer Beschreibung des Items.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public virtual string PrintItem()
    {
        return Name + " (" + Tier.ToString() + ") - " + Description;
    }

    public enum ItemTier
    {
        Common,
        Uncommon,
        Epic,
        Legendary,
        Heavengrade,
        Forbidden,
    }
}
private class ItemCodeDes
    {
        public ItemCodeDes(string ItemCode)
        {
            if (ItemCode.Length < 5) return;

            InterfaceCode = ushort.Parse(ItemCode[0].ToString(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            SubtypeCode = ushort.Parse(ItemCode[1].ToString(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            ItemId = ushort.Parse(ItemCode.Substring(2, 3), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);

            if (ItemCode.Length > 5)
                Generationspecifics = ItemCode.Substring(5);
        }
        public ushort InterfaceCode { get; }
        public ushort SubtypeCode { get; }
        public ushort ItemId { get; }
        public string Generationspecifics { get; } = "";
    }
```

Comment: You would presumably have to use Reflection.

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre]?

Comment: @GuruStron There should be everything you need to reproduce the "Problem". [CS0704](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0704?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0704))

Comment: @MP9 there isn't, please provide actual code for the `Iitem` interface. You probably want to use `static abstract` members in the interface (added in C# 11).

Comment: What is `Iitem`, what is `ItemCodeDes`? What is `InterfaceCode`  and `SubtypeCode`? There is definitely not enough info to copy-paste the code and repro the issue.

Comment: You need `static abstract`. [This works](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEUCuA7AHwAEAmARgFgAoagYQDoAVGAZwwB5m2BJDGAWwB8ACgCUAbmrUiAZgAEpObWoBvanI0L5RMkgUo5XDoxGi5AdwAWMWIbkg53AJZ9+6zWqqbvCsgE5hRnpuPD4oADMAQzAYWggAExgJdw0AX2p0mipZOSdQmyiYxxcBVRStXz1I4DYoaIw5HBZLaAaAZRxgDABPAAdYhJg5FTkAcxgMcTlM7xydKpqMOrAGppaoBpCwwoHE4bGJqczM6W0SQ1YMXgF7Ytcyr0053Ubm1rkOrr7doZHxyemcgAvHIAAySR4aZ56NbvLYFaI/fb/I7AsEQ1JAA===). [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/static-abstracts-in-interfaces?source=recommendations)

Comment: Possibly you need to use newly introduced `static abstract` interface members. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Wait, `Iitem` is a _class_ ?

Comment: Although, I would never have guessed that `Iitem` was a class!! Static abstract properties only work on interfaces, so you might have to refactor

Comment: @Fildor yes it sadly is. I tried to change it to an interface, but it breaks so much

Comment: (And this is why it's important to include a full MRE, even if *you* think you've included everything!)

Comment: @canton7 true that, sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Start feeling like always bumping into walls? _Maybe_ it's time to take a step back and rethink some architecture ... (hate to say this).

Comment: Would it be better to create an interface "below" `Iitem` containig `SubtypeCode` and `InterfaceCode`?

Comment: Really hard to tell. This seems to be one instance of when you pull a little string, the whole sweatshirt falls apart. And I personally would question that "efficiently saving and re-generating objects from hex-strings".

Comment: @Fildor I can save (and transport) every object with 5 characters (+additionals for special stuff) instead of saving every object to a json with 100+ variables.

Comment: Maybe you can "save" it if you can upgrade from 3.1 ... is that an option?

Comment: @Fildor yeah, I think I will do that. It really pains me because I wanted to wait for the next long term supported "plattform" to migrate, but I guess I don't have any better options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a good & clean solution to my problem (without using Reflection)?

There is, but it will require you to migrate to latest language version. This will enable option to use [static abstract members in interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/static-abstracts-in-interfaces?source=recommendations). Introduce corresponding interface and then use it:

```cs
public interface IIitem // probably you will need to use better name
{
    public static abstract ushort SubtypeCode { get; } 
    public static abstract ushort InterfaceCode { get; } 
}

public class Iitem : IIitem
{
   // ...
}
```

And constrain the generic parameter:

```cs
public static T AsType<T>(string ItemCode) where T : Iitem, IIitem
{
   // ...
}
```

If you can't upgrade to support the new language version then you will need to use reflection or refactor the approach (if I correctly understand the case - I usually used in similar case attributes on types and build static dictionaries mapping from type to codes and vise versa, hence "caching" reflection).

Comment: I feel like if you opt to use (runtime / on-the-fly, not only one-time-on-start-up) reflection, you can kiss "this is for _efficiently_ saving and re-generating objects from hex-strings" good-bye.

Comment: @Fildor you can "cache" reflection. For example like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62454454/2501279). Or in this case static dictionaries might work (need to see more code).

Comment: At least, you'd need to do some "magic". That's what I meant. Naive reflection won't cut it, I guess.

Comment: I upgraded to the latest language version and implemented the interface like you suggested. Thank you very much!

Comment: @MP9 glad it helped! Small P.S. - C# generics are not templates (if you come from C++ background - check out [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/differences-between-cpp-templates-and-csharp-generics))