# C# Template Function: Accessing static abstract members throws System.BadImageFormatException

Tags: c#, templates, abstract

I have asked a similar question before and this is more or less a follow up question.
([C# Template Function: Cannot do non-virutal member lookup in 'T' because it is a type parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76264403/14937551))

I want to access a static abstract variable in a template function:

```
public static T AsType<T>(...) where T : ICode
{
    //...
    if(InterfaceCode != T.InterfaceCode) return null;
    if(SubtypeCode != T.SubtypeCode) return null;
    //...
}
```

with

```
public interface ICode
{
    public static abstract ushort SubtypeCode { get; }
    public static abstract ushort InterfaceCode { get; }
}
```

Whenever I try to run this code following exception is thrown:

```
'T.InterfaceCode' threw an exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException'
```

I upgraded my project from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 7 recently, because I wanted to use this "feature" (and it was a suggested solution to my last question)

Please let me know if you need more background information. Thanks for your help!

Reproduce-able example:

```
internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AsType<Test>(1, 3);
        }
        public static T AsType<T>(ushort InterfaceCode, ushort SubtypeCode) where T : ICode
        {
            //...
            if (InterfaceCode != T.InterfaceCode) return default(T);
            if (SubtypeCode != T.SubtypeCode) return default(T);
            //...
            return default(T);
        }
        public interface ICode
        {
            public static abstract ushort SubtypeCode { get; }
            public static abstract ushort InterfaceCode { get; }
        }
        public class Item : ICode
        {
            public static ushort SubtypeCode { get; } = 1;
            public static ushort InterfaceCode { get; } = 2;
        }
        public class Test : Item
        {
            public static new ushort InterfaceCode { get; } = 1;
            public static new ushort SubtypeCode { get; } = 3;
        }
    }
```

NOTE: It does NOT throw this error. It it only displayed in the debug environment (VS2022) when displaying `T.InterfaceCode`.

Comment: Please can you provide a [mcve] so that we can reproduce the issue without guessing at the rest of your code? (Just enough to reproduce the problem - we don't need any of your real business code.)

Comment: @JonSkeet this should do, right?

Comment: Well it would be slightly better if it were in a class declaration so we could *literally* just copy/paste/compile/run, but it's close enough. However, when I put that into a `Program` class in a .NET 7 console app, it doesn't produce the exception. Does *just that code* throw the exception for you? Can you confirm that your TargetFramework is just net7.0?

Comment: @JonSkeet when debugging (stepping through) and hovering over `T.InterfaceCode` it shows `'T.InterfaceCode' threw an exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException'` and it doesn't seem to be working when inheriting the class Item either (`class Test : Item {}`...)

Comment: What happens when you just run from the command line though, with just `dotnet run`? If this is *only* showing up when stepping through code in the debugger, that's important information.

Comment: - updated reproduce-able example to show what i mean

Comment: Your updated code still doesn't throw any exception when I run it from the command line - and I don't know whether it does for you, either.

Comment: @JonSkeet it doesn't display any errors. Just noticed that it is working fine when Item inherits directly from ICode. I only tested it with inheriting the Item class.

Comment: Okay, it sounds like this is *just* a debugger issue then.

Comment: @JonSkeet Not really. In the provided example is `InterfaceCode` 1 and `T.InterfaceCode` should also be 1. Why does this check fail? Is it because I dont inherit ICode directly?

Comment: Well now you're asking about a completely different problem. You reported an exception, so I expected to see an exception. If you're now surprised at the value returned, you should say so - that's *nowhere* in the question. It's very frustrating trying to help someone when the ground keeps shifting. That's why it's always useful to provide a [mcve] - but one which *actually* reproduces the problem that your question describes.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I identified the real problem and found a solution.

As shown in the reproduce-able example I tried to inherit the class `Item` onto `Test` and hide the base members. Of course this won't work because these members are not from `ICode`.

The error on my side was to think it was an error from .NET 7 just because the debugger showed an exception when hovering over `T.InterfaceCode`. Because of this exception when trying to display the value, I was unable to detect the mistake from above.

I was able to solve it with inheriting `ICode` onto every subclass of `Item`.
(`class Test : Item, ICode {...}`)

Anyways, thanks for your help!