# How to get object type of c# List

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am making a component for my Blazor Server App. This component gets a List with object of type x and must display this List in a table. I got it to work so far, but I still have to tell te component the type of the objects in the List (first line of code). How can I get the second (commented) line to work?

**.cs file:**

```
private PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(Person).GetProperties();
//private PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(people.GetType).GetProperties();

private List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
private List<string> columns;
private string database = "Name'Address'Region'Country";

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    base.OnInitialized();

    columns = new List<string>();

    foreach(var item in database.Split("'"))
    {
        columns.Add(item);
    }

    people.Add(new Person
    {
        Name = "John Doe",
        Address = "Somewhere 111",
        City = "Somewhere",
        Region = "Elsewhere",
        PostalCode = "11153AA",
        Country = "Earth"
    });

}
```

**.razor file**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @foreach (var item in properties)
            {
                if (columns.Contains(item.Name))
                {
                    <th>@(item.Name)</th>
                }
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in people)
        {
            <tr>
                @foreach (var prop in properties)
                {
                    if (columns.Contains(prop.Name))
                    {
                        <td>@(prop.GetValue(item))</td>
                    }
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried using `private PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(people.GetType).GetProperties();` but the component didn't work with that. How to fix?

Comment: `typeof(people.GetType)` You surely mean `typeof(people.GetType())`, otherwise this won't compile.

Comment: `private PropertyInfo[] properties;` and OnInitialized: `properties = typeof(people.GetType()).GetProperties();` does not work

Comment: @Jeremy seem my answer, it should be `people.GetType().GetProperties()`. `typeof` is only for type names (or generic type parameter names).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your are trying to create a generic table component for Blazor. Your component should declare a generic type parameter: `@typeparam T`. Then you can get the properties using: `typeof(T).GetProperties()`.

**`Table.razor`:**

```
@using System.Reflection
@typeparam T

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @foreach (var item in properties)
            {
                if (columns.Contains(item.Name))
                {
                    <th>@(item.Name)</th>
                }
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Items)
        {
            <tr>
                @foreach (var prop in properties)
                {
                    if (columns.Contains(prop.Name))
                    {
                        <td>@(prop.GetValue(item))</td>
                    }
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public List<T> Items { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Database { get; set; }
    
    private List<string> columns;
    private PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();

        columns = new List<string>();

        foreach(var item in Database.Split("'"))
        {
            columns.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Component can be used like this:

```
<Table Items="@people" Database="@database" />

@code {
    private List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
    private string database = "Name'Address'Region'Country";

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        people.Add(new Person
        {
            Name = "John Doe",
            Address = "Somewhere 111",
            City = "Somewhere",
            Region = "Elsewhere",
            PostalCode = "11153AA",
            Country = "Earth"
        });
    }
}
```

[Online demo](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/x3zeksjz)

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#typeof-operator):

> The `typeof` operator obtains the `System.Type` instance for a type. The argument to the `typeof` operator **must be the name of a type or a type parameter**

So you can't use (and don't need to) the `typeof` here. The [`Object.GetType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gettype?view=net-7.0) already returns the type:

```
System.Type type = people.GetType();
```

Since `List<T>` is generic type to get person type from it you will need to do some reflection manipulation. For example:

```
Type type = people.GetType();
if (type.IsConstructedGenericType)
{
    var personType = type.GenericTypeArguments[0]; // == typeof(Person)
}
```

Note that in general reflection is quite slow and I would argue that it should be avoided if possible (for multiple reasons, including compile time safety for example). There are workarounds to negate the effect (for example [cache reflection handling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62454454/2501279)) but in general I would recommend against using it or consider looking into [source generators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview) which can be used as substitute in quite a lot of cases.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the `typeof()` operator this way:

```
typeof(people.GetType).GetProperties();
```

`typeof()` requires a type name, [one that is known at compile time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#typeof-operator) - it seems what you're trying to do is get the element type of any `List<T>` without knowing in advance what type `T` it was instantiated with. You need to get the type using an at-runtime facility, which is what the `GetType()` method does (don't try to combine it with `typeof()`). Then query for the generic type `T` that the List was instantiated with.

Try this on your `List<Person> people` instance:

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
...
// elementType should now be the same as typeof(Person)
Type elementType = people.GetType().GetGenericArguments().First();
```